# Define TabLayout style in theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-tablayout

I have two different styles of `TabLayout` in my app:

```
<style name="TabLayoutPower" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="TabLayoutFree" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="tabTextColor">@android:color/black</item>
</style>
```

How can I define the default `TabLayout` style for a theme? I cannot find any info which item name should I use to build my theme. I'd like to add the TabLayout the same way I added my listview:

```
<style name="Free" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_red</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/main_bg_light</item>
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: nope . I had to implement the view change manually.

Comment: @sliwkacz, I found you an answer that actually works! Can you mark that one as the correct one?

Answer (score 16):

For Support Library `TabLayout`, you can set `tabStyle` attribute in your theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="tabStyle">@style/AppTheme.TabLayout</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.TabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="tabTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If I use `tabStyle`, it doesn't compile.

Comment: @MarkBuikema it works with `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`, but not necessarily with standard `TabLayout`

Answer (score 7):

If you wan to use 2 different styles for your **`TabLayout`** based on theme of your application then you should define your style inside **`attrs.xml`**

here is the Sample code for that

> First you create an **attrs.xml** file ( [**Like this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdzQ8.png) )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="textColor" format="reference|color" />
    <attr name="backColor" format="reference|color" />
    <attr name="myTabStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

> define various theme as per your requirements inside **`styles.xml`**

Note: i have used 3 different themes for demo

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="tabStyle">@style/TabLayoutPower</item>
        <item name="textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="backColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabStyle">@style/TabLayoutFree</item>
        <item name="backColor">#FF00</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme3" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#ff00</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff0</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#0a91d4</item>
        <item name="tabStyle">@style/TabLayoutNew</item>
        <item name="textColor">#FF00</item>
        <item name="backColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TabLayoutPower" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TabLayoutFree" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@android:color/holo_blue_bright</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TabLayoutNew" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Now use this `style` in your **`TabLayout`** like this inside **layout.xml** files

Use like this **`style="?myTabStyle"`** it will select `style` based on current theme of your application

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThemeOne"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Theme One" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThemeTwo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Theme Two" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnThemeThree"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Theme Three" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        style="?myTabStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> sample code  of `TabsActivity` to change theme

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PrefManager prefManager;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private Button btnThemeOne, btnThemeTwo, btnThemeThree;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        getTheme().applyStyle(prefManager.getTheme(), true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabs);


        btnThemeOne = findViewById(R.id.btnThemeOne);

        btnThemeOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(TabsActivity.this, "Applying theme one", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                prefManager.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                recreate();
            }
        });

        btnThemeTwo = findViewById(R.id.btnThemeTwo);

        btnThemeTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(TabsActivity.this, "Applying theme two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                prefManager.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme2);
                recreate();
            }
        });


        btnThemeThree = findViewById(R.id.btnThemeThree);

        btnThemeThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(TabsActivity.this, "Applying theme three", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                prefManager.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme3);
                recreate();
            }
        });

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }


    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "THREE");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

> PrefManager class to save theme info

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class PrefManager {

    // Shared preferences file name
    private final String PREF_NAME = "theme-pref";
    private final String THEME = "theme";
    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public int getTheme() {
        return pref.getInt(THEME, R.style.AppTheme);
    }

    public void setTheme(int themeId) {
        editor.putInt(THEME, themeId);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

> you can check the output video of above code

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uup072IDGd0

Answer (score -2):

You can find that name in Android theme -

```
<item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/Your.Style</item>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    <style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="">
        <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="tabTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

<style name="Free" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/main_red</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/main_bg_light</item>
        <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/MyListView</item>
<item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: For me works- just leave parent empty and apply to android:tabWidgetStyle ;)