# Where to put XML styles

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

## Question 1

I want all `Toolbar` to look the same, without setting styles in all of them,
so I though I would set the app theme for it. One of the things I wanted all them to have is the `colorControlNormal` atribute. These were my attempts:

*Code sample 1*:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ToolbarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/toolbarColorControlNormal</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

*Code sample 2*:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/toolbarColorControlNormal</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In *Code sample 1*, I tried to create a custom style for the `Toolbar` atributes, and set it to the theme, but it didn't work.

In *Code sample 2*, I set the attribute globally and worked. However, affects other components too, so it's not valid.

- Why isn't *Code sample 1* working ?

---

## Question 2

I need to change the `tabTextColor` and `tabSelectedTextColor` attributes of all `TabLayout`, so I tried this:

*Code sample 3*:

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/TabsStyle</item>
  </style>

  <style name="TabsStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextColor">@color/tabTextColor</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/tabSelectedTextColor</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

But it's not working, the only way I got it working is manually setting them in XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    [...]
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/tabTextColor"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tabSelectedTextColor" />
```

- Why isn't *Code sample 3* working ?

---

Last, I will upvote any reference to good style & theme guides/books. I really need to improve at this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did set your theme in AndroidManifes?

Comment: @fisher3421 The second code sample wouldn't have worked if I didn't.

Comment: I highly recommend [Android-Material-Themes-Demo](https://github.com/StevenByle/Android-Material-Themes-Demo) in the github. Learn by doing. Nice Overview in the [README.md](https://github.com/StevenByle/Android-Material-Themes-Demo/blob/master/README.md) on Styles And Themes.

Comment: Are you using [TabHost](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) and [TabWidget](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html)? `tabWidgetStyle` applies to these controls and not to `TabLayout` which, it appears, doesn't have a default like the other widgets. If you can clarify this point, it will help to give an answer. For use of the `tabWidgetStyle` attribute see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/widget/TabHost.java#78).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Globally specify a color for the back arrow in the `Toolbar`**

This is not as straightforward as it probably should be, but try the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- style the back arrow -->
    <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/NavButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="NavButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
    <item name="android:tint">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

It is `android:tint` that will change the color of the back arrow.

In general, the default toolbar style is set by the attribute `toolbarStyle`. In the XML below, it is set to `@style/MyToolbarStyle`.
`MyToolbarStyle` defines three attributes that will be used for all toolbars within the app. Here is what one looks like:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbarStyle</item>
        <item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="titleTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextColor">@android:color/holo_green_light</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/vermillion</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image]

As you can see, `MyToolbarStyle` sets the value of the three attributes. Unfortunately, this approach does not work for all attributes such as `colorControlNormal` which, if specified in the theme, will change the color of the back arrow.

---

**Regarding the question about `TabLayout`:**

There is no pretty solution to globally define attributes for `TabLayout`. You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47319200/6287910) and just overlay `Widget.Design.TabLayout` but you will have to recreate all the attributes defined there and these attributes may change depending upon the version that is running. This works, but may be a problem to maintain. I don't think that it is a good solution.

Another solution is to create your own custom `TabLayout`. It will be very simple and will just define `tabTextAppearance` as a global default attribute for `TabLayout`. The entire custom layout will look like this:

```
public class MyTabLayout extends TabLayout {
    public MyTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.tabTextAppearance);
    }
}
```

Once you replace all references to `TabLayout` to `MyTabLayout`, you will be able to do the following in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyTabStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTabStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

This will make the tab text colors red and green but they can be colors that you choose. You can now declare a `TabLayout` in XML and have the default style apply to it without having to explicitly specify a style/theme.

The underlying issue is that the CTORs for `TabLayout` do not use `defStyleResource` which defines the default style to apply to the view that is defined in the theme and `tabWidgetStyle` is not it.. (See [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java#292).)  The custom layout `MyTabLayout` circumvents the problem. However, this does raise the question about whether there is a reason the `defStyleResource` is not used and maybe we are diving into a briar patch that we may best avoid.

These methods do work, but I have not fully tested them. You will have to make the determination about whether it is better to do what is described here or to simply define the style on a view-by-view basis.

If someone has a standard, Android-approved way to specify `TabLayout` attributes globally, I will be glad to hear about it.

---

Comment: Thanks for answering. I really was focusing on a simple question here, which is: why would I add `<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbarStyle</item>` to the main theme, if it won't work unless I explicitly set it with `android:theme="@style/MyToolbarStyle` ? I though the Widget would read the attrs from the main theme, why do I have to set it twice ? Isn't there for all Widgets to read the attrs from the main theme ?

Comment: @JonZarate Ah, but you don't have to add `android:theme="@style/MyToolbarStyle`. Do you see that in the XML that I provided? Bring up a simple project with the XML and java code I supplied and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Yes I see, but `colorControlNormal` isn't working. I updated post and questions.

Comment: @JonZarate What do you expect `colorControlNormal` to do for you in a `Toolbar`?

Comment: Change the back arrow color

Comment: @JonZarate See the update at the end of the post regarding `toolbarNavigationButtonStyle`

Comment: Thanks, that made it. It wouldn't hurt to delete the content that doesn't address the questions though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

### Question 1

The difference between a *theme* and a *style* is subtle, and things are confused more than they ought to be because you define both of them using a `<style>` tag. But even though they both use `<style>` tags, they behave differently.

Attributes specified in the *theme* of a view apply to that view and all of its children. Attributes specified in the *style* of a view apply only to that view. Additionally, there are some attributes called *theme attributes* that only work when they're a part of a theme. `colorControlNormal` is a theme attribute; setting it in a style won't have any effect.

*Code sample 1* doesn't work because your `<item name="colorControlNormal">` element is defined in a style and not a theme.

*Code sample 2* changes everything because now `colorControlNormal` is in your **app's** theme, so it applies to all elements in your app that care about it.

Unfortunately, I believe there is no way to simply specify a theme to use for every `Toolbar` in your app. You will have to settle for one of the following:

**1) Use the `android:theme` attribute**

For this, you'd create a style like:

```
<style name="MyToolbarTheme">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/toolbarColorControlNormal</item>
</style>
```

And then, on every `<Toolbar>` tag, you'd add

```
android:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"
```

**2) Create a custom subclass of `Toolbar`**

Again, you'd need a style like the above. Then you'd create a class like this:

```
public class MyToolbar extends Toolbar {

    public MyToolbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(wrapContext(context), attrs);
    }

    private static Context wrapContext(Context context) {
        return new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.MyToolbarTheme);
    }
}
```

And use it in your layout files like this:

```
<com.example.stackoverflow.MyToolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

This works by taking the `Context` instance that your toolbar is being inflated with and changing its theme to your custom toolbar theme. Since this (wrapped) context is only used to create your custom toolbar, it won't affect other views in your app.

For what it's worth, this is what I've done in my apps.

### Question 2

Here, the *why* is a little simpler: `android:tabWidgetStyle` is the default style for [`TabWidget`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html), not for `TabLayout`. In fact, I'm not aware of any defined default style for `TabLayout`.

Again, you have two options. You can create a style and apply it to every `<TabLayout>` tag, or you can create a custom subclass and use that instead of `TabLayout`:

```
public class MyTabLayout extends TabLayout {

    public MyTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        int normalColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tabTextColor);
        int selectedColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.tabSelectedTextColor);
        setTabTextColors(normalColor, selectedColor);
    }
}
```

### Further reading

Here's some material I read when I was learning this stuff:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html

https://medium.com/google-developers/theming-with-appcompat-1a292b754b35

https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/08/contextcompat-getcolor-getdrawable.html

Comment: Even though I like your answer better (more organized & clear to the point), the other answer gave a solution that fits me better (through XML). I can only upvote you. Thanks.

Comment: @JonZarate no worries. I didn't know about `toolbarNavigationButtonStyle` so it's a win for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on res folder, choose New --> Android resource file, set the same name for the new file "styles", in Available qualifiers: choose the last item "Version" and finally set "Platform API level" 21.