# Android set different styles to Views in code / dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-styles

I want to dynamically add a custom styles to  textviews in code. I can use the following  workaround to do this when there is only textview in question:

[android set style in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code)

However, if I try this method and create a template.xml file with 2 textview, each with a different style applied, this no longer works.

i.e. my template file will look something like this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <TextView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is a template"
            style="@style/my_style" />
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is another template"
            style="@style/my_style2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How do I extend this solution so it works with more than one textview and more than one style?

Comment: checkout this answer it will gives u a hint https://stackoverflow.com/a/55136904/7666442

Comment: May be you need to try to provide *Orientation* to *Linear Layout*.